# Quebrar a DIV em 3, ou mais, com colunas de tamanhos diferentes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Qual a melhor prática para contornar esse problema da imagem abaixo?

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}

.container-box {
  background-color: rgb(230, 228, 224);
  height: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
}

.content-box1 {
  background-color: rgb(28, 28, 28);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.4rem 0rem 0.4rem 0rem;
}

.content-box2 {
  background-color: rgb(72, 112, 136);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.4rem 0rem 0.4rem 0rem;
}

.content-box3 {
  background-color: rgb(160, 86, 117);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.4rem 0rem 0.4rem 0rem;
}

.content-box4 {
  background-color: rgb(120, 94, 192);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0.4rem 0rem 0.4rem 0rem;
}

.a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: ease-in-out 0.2s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-box container-box">
  <div class="flex-box container-box">
    <div class="content-box1 a" style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; height: 400px;">Conteúdo 01</div>
    <div class="content-box2 a" style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; height: 200px;">Conteúdo 02</div>
    <div class="content-box3 a" style="max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px; height: 200px;">Conteúdo 03</div>
    <div class="flex-box container-box a">
      <div class="content-box4" style="max-width: 400px; min-width: 200px; width: 400px; height: 200px;">Conteúdo 04</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Print do resultado da DIV quebrada]

Não consegui resolver adequadamente. Faz um tempo que não trabalho com marcação e estou estudando. Me lembro que já fiz isso com GRID. Mas, o detalhe principal é que preciso transformar esse problema numa solução maior. Preciso resolver isso em `<table>` (tabelas). Alguém saberia a melhor prática?

Comment: Como você quer deixar a div?

Comment: Cara esse layout vc não consegue com flex, talvez com grid, usando `dense`, mas é provável que não fique perfeito. Agora, se vc que fazer isso com `table`, vc vai precisar de muito rowspan e colspan, nem justificaria... vc tem que dar um exemplo mais próximo da realidade final que vc precisa

Comment: Oi @MariaEduarda eu gostaria de deixar uma imagem no bloco preto (conteúdo 01) e nos demais colunas de texto. Sendo o último bloco, lilás (conteúdo 04), um botão feito em css inline. Estou tentando ajudar uma amiga. A ideia é usar isso em disparo de um e-mail (por isso as tabelas).

Comment: @hugocsl eu vou colar um link que é parecido. Veja:


https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a7/9b/f5/a79bf5ed820c2decd7d8e1bb0c597d8b.jpg

Em 2017 eu fiz alguns e-mails para essa empresa, mas lá não se usa tabela. Como minha amiga não tem acesso a ferramentas que ajudem nesse aspecto e está usando o Sublime, seria uma boa saber a melhor prática.

Eu pensei mesmo na Grid, como vc. disse, mas em e-mail quebraria tudo dependendo do browser de e-mail... =/

Comment: Então o melhor é usar grid, agora sobre a quebra de linha e etc sofreria quando o usuário recebesse aí é assunto pra outra pergunta, porque você poderia usar um `max-width` por exemplo pra setar a largura máxima de uma imagem pra caso o usuário que tenha uma tela pequena não fique com o email todo quebrado quando receber, agora se um usuário com tela grande receber pode ficar pequena, porém não vai ter problema de quebra. Isso pode ser ajustado é como deixar um objeto responsivo em uma página :)

Comment: O max-width eu uso. E grid pode ser a melhor solução sim. Vou testar. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beleza galera?

Essa semana eu consegui voltar no problema e, após estudar algumas horinhas, consegui solucionar.

Com grid é bem fácil. Foi bem rápido de fazer. Mas, não funciona para envios de e-mail, devido as limitações de renderização dos clientes de e-mail.

O que funcionou foi instalar o Foundation - https://www.npmjs.com/package/foundation-emails-template

Pelo foundation eu consigo organizar o layout necessário. Os templates que vêm instalados são simples, mas dá para criar soluções ali e gerar a build para envio de emkt com css inline. Funciona bem! Inclusive no outlook que é o pai dos bugs.

O e-mail que fiz pelo Node.js usando foundation não sei se dá para publicar aqui, pq é uma confusão de código.

Mas, vou deixar o layout com css grid para ajudar a galera. =)

**Agradeço a todos que de alguma forma me ajudaram a chegar no resultado.**

Também publiquei para visualizarem melhor. ^^
https://vedomi.com.br/refs/base-emkt-ved.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Base email marketing utilizando css grid</title>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css-emkt.css"> -->

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo:wght@400;700&amp;family=Poppins:wght@400;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<style rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

/*  Css - Cascading Style Sheets   | Main  */

:root {
/* variáveis css */
--color-background: #0154A4;
--color-primary-lighter-saturated: #F0C891;
--color-primary-lighter: #D3CBBD;
--color-primary-light: #C8BEAC;
--color-primary: #5082C8;
--color-primary-dark: #01428d;
--color-primary-darker: #08317E;
--color-secondary: #04BF58;
--color-secondary-dark: #03A04A;
--color-title-in-primary: #C50210;
--color-text-in-primary: #282828 ;
--color-text-title: #F1F0ED;
--color-text-complement: #C50210;
--color-text-base: #282828;
--color-line-in-white: #F1F0ED;
--color-input-background: #C50210;
--color-button-text: #F1F0ED;
--color-box-base: #C50210;
--color-box-footer: #C50210;
--color-small-info: #90B9F2;
--colors-menu-info-1: #0154A4;
--colors-menu-info-2: #FFC20F;
--colors-menu-info-3: #061756;
--colors-menu-info-4: #F1F0ED;

/* tamanho da fonte padrao: 16px - 100% - 1rem */
font-size: 100%; /* controle das medidas rem */
}

*   {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
height: 100vh;
}

body {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

body,
input,
button,
textarea {
/* agrupamento da fonte //
font: 500 1.6rem Poppins; */
font-weight: 500;
font-family: Poppins;
font-size: 1.4rem;
color: var(--color-text-base);
}

.banner {
background: var(--color-background);
grid-area: banner;
}

.banner img {
display:table;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;

min-height: 315px;
max-height: 315px;
}

.message {
background: var(--color-primary);
grid-area: message;
}

.message p {
background: var(--color-primary);
font-size: 1em;
padding: 10px;
color: var(--color-text-title);
grid-column: 1;

display:table;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
  
margin: 0 auto;
}

.message-text {
background: var(--color-primary);
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
margin: 10px;

font-weight: 300;
overflow: hidden;

/* white-space: nowrap; */

text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

color: var(--color-text-title);

display: flex;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;

min-height: 100px;
max-height: 130px;
}

.picture {
background: #E01E5C;
grid-area: picture;
grid-row: 3/5;
overflow: hidden;
}

.picture img {
grid-column: 1;
grid-row: 1/3;
align-self: end;

display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;

z-index: -1;
}

.picture p {
background: #0c5e69;
font-size: 1em;
padding: 10px;
color: var(--colors-menu-info-3);
grid-column: 1;
grid-row: 2;

display: table;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
  
margin: 0 auto;

align-self: end;

margin-top: -4rem;
}

.offer {
background: var(--colors-menu-info-2);
grid-area: offer;
}

.offer-text {
padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
margin: 10px;
margin-top: 32px;

font-weight: 300;

text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;

color: var(--color-text-in-primary);

display: flex;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

.button {
grid-area: button;
grid-column: 2/3;
grid-row: 4/5;

background-color: var(--color-line-in-white); 

height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.button a {
background-color: var(--color-secondary-dark); 
transition: background-color .5s;
text-decoration: none;

text-align: center; 
color: var(--color-button-text); 

font-weight: 600;
letter-spacing: 0.1rem;

width: 12rem; 
height: 4rem; 

border: 3px solid; 
border-radius: 32rem; 

display: flex; 
align-items: center; 
justify-content: center; 
text-decoration: none;

margin-left: 11.5%;
margin-top: 6%;
}  

.button a:hover {
background-color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.section {
background: var(--color-line-in-white);
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  
display: flex;
box-sizing: border-box;
align-items: top;
justify-content: center;
  
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
width: 100vw; /* largura */
max-width: 700px;
/*border: 5px solid yellow;*/
}

.container {
background: var(--color-line-in-white);
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
  
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 40%;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 0.5fr 0.8fr 0.3fr;
  
gap: 4px;
  
grid-template-areas: "banner banner"
                                  "message message"
                                  "picture offer"
                                  "button button";
  
justify-content: center;

min-width: 590px;
max-width: 630px;

max-height: 830px;
}

/*.container > div {
   background: none;
}*/
</style>

<body>
<div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="https://www.vedomi.com.br/refs/emkt-img-01.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="message">
            <!-- Máximo de 42 caracteres -->
            <h1 class="message-text">Subtítulo padrão para comunicado simples.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="https://www.vedomi.com.br/refs/emkt-img-01.jpg">
            <p>LEGENDA</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offer">
            <p>
                <h2 class="offer-text">Descrição</h1>
                <h6 class="offer-text">Texto de preenchimento básico para espaço reservado apenas para amostra de texto.</h6>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="https://www.vedomi.com.br" target="_blank">Ação</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternativa usando flexbox:

Tem uma guide que super recomendo para leitura sobre flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.section {
  background: gray;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  height: 100px;
  flex: 1;
}

.content.small {
  flex: 2;
}

.content.big {
  flex: 6;
}



/* color styles [ignore] */
.content {
  font-family: arial;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.content:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

.content:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
}

.content:nth-child(3) {
  background: blue;
}

.purple {
  background: purple !important;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content small">Conteúdo 01</div>
        <div class="content big">Conteúdo 02</div>
        <div class="content small">Conteúdo 03</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content purple">Conteúdo 04</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

- Adicionei 3 colunas e 1 linha com 1 coluna logo abaixo.
- Para testes, adicione mais uma coluna na linha de cima, só duplicar o trecho `<div class="content>`;
- Você pode também aumentar ou diminuir a largura de cada coluna, utilizando a propriedade `flex`;

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Olá Roberto, beleza? A sua solução funciona bem, mas não atende ao que eu preciso, pois o "conteúdo 03" precisaria ocupar dois espaços. E como por flex não é possível pq. trabalha em apenas uma dimensão, só com grid mesmo. Mas, muito obrigado mesmo assim! ^^

Eu vou responder em seguida. Resolvi a questão. =)

Comment: Olá @EduardoLouzada, tudo tranquilo e ai? Mas dai você poderia modificar o valor flex de cada elemento. Se por exemplo você editar a classe small para big na div do conteúdo 3, ele ficara com o tamanho maior que o conteúdo 1, e o mesmo que o conteúdo 2. Porque agora ele tem o flex com valor 6, e não 2.

No final ficaria:
Conteúdo 1: flex 2
Conteúdo 2: flex 6
Conteúdo 3: flex 6

De um espaço de 14 blocos, 12 seriam só do conteúdo 2 e 3, sacou?
Também podederia ser:
Conteúdo 1: flex 1
Conteúdo 2 e 3: flex 2

Que daria na mesma. Enfim, mas fico feliz que conseguiu resolver, abraços!